# Is there a builtin alternative to std::put_time for GCC <5?

Tags: c++, time, formatting, gcc4

I'm stuck on GCC4.8 for the time being. I want to print out the current time as something other than seconds. If `put_time` worked, my code would be something simple, like this:

```
std::cout << std::setw(24) << std::put_time(c_time, "[%T%z %F] ");
```

Without `put_time`, I'd have to access the elements of `c_time` manually and do all the formatting manually, which would be a pain in the a** and is something I'm much rather avoid if possible. Note that this ***does not*** mean that I never want to interact with C in any way, even indirectly -- I'd just like to avoid coding in C directly if possible.

However, I can't find any alternatives to `std::put_time`, aside from `strftime`, which I'd like to avoid because it requires almost double the lines of code and is a lot harder to read, at least for me. Also, this is C++, not C, so I'd like to steer clear of C functions whenever possible.

Am I missing something? Is there a builtin alternative to `std::put_time` which works under GCC 4.8?

Note that it doesn't have to work in exactly the same way -- if it, say, printed it directly to the output, rather than being a stream manipulator, that would be perfectly fine too, as would a function which returned a `std::string` containing the formatted time.

I've done a good bit of Googling and found [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/), but that doesn't work because it doesn't have anything to format the time automatically. I'd still have to do it manually, and I'm pretty sure it would be *more* work, since I'd have to parse the number of seconds since the epoch into a year, month, day, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no functions other than [`put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) for the outputing of time provided in the [`chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) or the [`iomanip`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) library.

The `ctime` library does provide: [`strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime), [`ctime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime), and [`asctime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/asctime).

Since http://stackoverflow.com does not permit questions about finding 3<sup>rd</sup> party libraries, I'm going to guess that you're just asking for someone to direct you on the use of `strftime`? `std::put_time(c_time, "[%T%z %F] ")` could be written in the format:

```
char foo[24];

if(0 < strftime(foo, sizeof(foo), "[%T%z %F] ", c_time)) cout << foo << endl;
```

Comment: I was asking if there were any built-in libraries to do it, which is on-topic. You've answered that. Also, Stack Overflow allows you to say, "This is a library which solves your problem"; it's only asking specifically for offsite resources that's banned. In other words, if you know of a third-party library, you can mention it; that just wasn't what I was asking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

> Also, this is C++, not C, so I'd like to steer clear of C functions whenever possible.

That's a pretty silly mindset. `put_time` uses `std::strftime` underneath the hood.

[ext.manip#10](http://eel.is/c++draft/ext.manip#10)

> *Returns:* An object of unspecified type ... where the function `f` is defined as:

```
template <class charT, class traits>
void f(basic_ios<charT, traits>& str, const struct tm* tmb, const charT* fmt) {
  /* ... */
  typedef time_put<charT, Iter> TimePut;

  /* ... */
}
```

And `time_put`'s definition is in [locale.time.put.virtuals#1](http://eel.is/c++draft/locale.time.put.virtuals#1):

> *Effects:* Formats the contents of the parameter `t` into characters placed on the output sequence `s`. Formatting is controlled by the
>   parameters format and modifier, interpreted identically as the format
>   specifiers in the string argument to the standard library function
>   `strftime()` ...

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to rip off the definition of `std::put_time` from a later GCC's header, since the underlying facility `std::time_put` is still present in GCC 4.8 and the definition is not very complicated. This is copied from GCC 7.4's `<iomanip>` and edited for clarity:

```cpp
#if __GNUC__ && __GNUC__ < 5
#include <ostream>  // std::basic_ostream
#include <ios>      // std::ios_base
#include <locale>   // std::use_facet, std::time_put
#include <iterator> // std::ostreambuf_iterator

template<typename CharT>
struct _put_time                   
{                                                                     
  const std::tm* time;
  const char *fmt;
};
    
template<typename CharT>
inline _put_time<CharT>
put_time(const std::tm* time, const CharT* fmt)
{ return { time, fmt }; }
  
template<typename CharT, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &os, _put_time<CharT> f)
{   
  typedef typename std::ostreambuf_iterator<CharT, Traits> Iter;
  typedef std::time_put<CharT, Iter> TimePut;
      
  const CharT* const fmt_end = f.fmt + Traits::length(f.fmt);
  const TimePut& mp = std::use_facet<TimePut>(os.getloc());
    
  std::ios_base::iostate err = std::ios_base::goodbit;
  try {
    if (mp.put(Iter(os.rdbuf()), os, os.fill(), f.time, f.fmt, fmt_end).failed())
      err |= std::ios_base::badbit;
  }
  catch (...) {
    err |= std::ios_base::badbit;
  }  
   
  if (err)
    os.setstate(err);

  return os;
} 

#endif
```